# Python use of a:[1,3]?

Tags: python

What does this line mean in python 3.x?

```
a:[1,3]
```

**Source :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yX8KuPZCAMo

**Time: 17:40**

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: the link explains a[3:4] I am asking a:[1,3] @EdChum

Comment: That looks like invalid syntax to me.

Comment: But in the video , it is working

Comment: @John Gordon See video and the time it is executing

Comment: Is it a dictionary or a List? coz dictionary is created like this a={"a_key":2,"akey1":4}??

Comment: duh... you need to view at 17:47 the code... and Aladdin can do the rest!

Comment: @ZF007 Well spotted. It is a dictionary in the video. shiteme, dictionaries can look like `dict_of_lists = {a: [b, 7], 3: [b, c]}`, if a, b, c were defined before creating the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax of a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python, a data structure which maps an index to another object.

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
{a: [1,3]}
```

In this case, `a` is a `Tensor` from [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and `[1,3]` are the values it will assume when the graph is executed.

IMO, you should invest your time into acquiring a better understanding of elementary [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.htm) and [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/) from Python before diving into Tensorflow.

Comment: Is it a dictionary or a List? coz dictionary is created like this a={"a_key":2,"akey1":4}??

Comment: It is a dictionary whose index is pointing to a list.

Answer (score 0):

In the video, a and b are `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` Objects. At time 17:40, the instructor uses a and b as keys and their respective values [1,3] and [2, 4]. At 17:45, in the pop_up, you can see the variable name, `feed_dict`. He is just creating a dictionary.

Comment: Is it a dictionary or a List? coz dictionary is created like this a={"a_key":2,"akey1":4}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us the whole context of the code.

```
{a:[1,3]}
```

defines a dictionary with key `a` and value `[1,3]`.

Comment: Is it a dictionary or a List? coz dictionary is created like this a={"a_key":2,"akey1":4}

Comment: Dict keys don't have to be strings; they can be any immutable value.  In this case, the key is a variable `a` which was previously defined.  And the value can be anything, in this case it's a list.

Answer (score -1):

OP takes a part of a Dictionary out of context which can be seen at timepoint 17:47min.

`a` is declared as `a = tf... etc` and thus has content and context.

[1,3] are list items.

then a:[1,3] in `dict`:

a     =  keyname.
[1,3] = values

try this:

```
a = 'alot of words for a keyname'
b = 17.47

my_dict = {a:["sing along song", "the voice of"], b:(12, 'candidates', None, "wins")}

print my_dict.keys()
```

Comment: Is it a dictionary or a List? coz dictionary is created like this a={"a_key":2,"akey1":4}

Comment: its dict with declared values. `a` is here a variable name that is brought in as you can see at 17:47 in the video.